# Hashmap iterators(keySet and entrySet) give different result

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I am trying to migrate a Java Web Start application to Java 1.7 platform from Java 1.6 platform. Server side is java 1.6 (WebSphere App. Server v8.5). Briefly application works as a desktop application and uses http-client to communicate with server and transfers data by using Java serialization.

I have experienced a strange case. If I run the Application in Java 1.6 everything is OK as expected. When running on Java 1.7 Application sends a Data Value Object(the DVO consists of other DVOs and a HashMap) at server-side in debug mode I can see the DVO but when I want to put a new object(not NULL!!!) I see the hashmap's element size increases but value is null.

Actual strange case is that. If you traverse hashmap over "KeySet" the result is different than traversing over "EntrySet". You can see result as below

```
HashMap map = getHashMapData();
System.out.println("####Iterate over keySet");
for (Iterator iterator = map.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Object  key = (Object) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(key +" : "+map.get(key));
}
System.out.println("####Iterate over entrySet");
for (Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();){
    Entry e = (Entry) it.next();
    System.out.println(e.getKey() +":"+ e.getValue());  
}
System.out.println("###sysout map");
System.out.println(map);
```

output

```
####Iterate over keySet
[4/11/14 9:33:14:737 EEST] 00000095 SystemOut     O persistData : null
[4/11/14 9:33:16:017 EEST] 00000095 SystemOut     O processCodeDVO : null
####Iterate over entrySet
[4/11/14 9:33:18:169 EEST] 00000095 SystemOut     O persistData:[27883271, 22644993]
[4/11/14 9:33:19:199 EEST] 00000095 SystemOut     O processCodeDVO:test.dvo.ProcessCodeDVO@a31742c
###sysout map
[4/11/14 9:33:21:414 EEST] 00000095 SystemOut     O {persistData=[27883271, 22644993], processCodeDVO=test.dvo.ProcessCodeDVO@a31742c}
```

What is the problem and any suggestion?

thanks.

Comment: This suggests that you may not have implemented `hashCode()` / `equals` correctly. It would really help if you could show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is in `getHashMapData()`. BTW, `Iterator` and `HashMap` are generic types and using them without specification of types may cause to unwanted results.

Comment: getHashMapData() simplifies code. It just returns a hashmap but problem occurs after that point.I can see only one just element(persistData) before adding. after putting processCodeDVO:test.dvo.ProcessCodeDVO@a31742c object I print out the result as above.

Comment: Jon, Neither hashCode() nor equals() is overridden for ProcessCodeDVO but I will check it for "persistData" object.BTW I couldn't supply complete code so that Map comes from client by using java serialization. Complete code has so many lines of io library.

Comment: persistData object is an ArrayList which includes BigDecimal. That is, Neither hashCode() nor equals() is overridden for persistData,too.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved. The problem occurred hashmap which has one element and deserialized before. I open a pmr and here is the answer "There are different APARs for the SDK 6.0.1 (also known as Java 1.6) and SDK 7.0 (also known as Java 1.7) that represent the same issue. Java 6.0.1 : IV56384 This is to be included in a future release The developers currently forcast it to be included in IBM SDK 6.0.1 SR8 Java 7.0 : IV36796 This is fixed in IBM SDK 7.0 SR4 or later".